# Convert string variables into ints in a dataset

Tags: python, dataset, recode

I'm trying to convert values from strings to ints in a certain column of a dataset. I tried using a for loop and even though the loop does seem to be iterating through the data it's failing to convert any of the variables. I'm certain that I'm making a super basic mistake but can't figure it out as I'm very new at this.

I downloaded a data file from https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/majunbajun/himalayan-climbing-expeditions

Then proceeded to process the data so that I can analyse it statistically.

Here's the start of the code

```
#import pandas
import pandas as pd
#import expeditions as csv file
exp = pd.read_csv('C:\\file\\path\\to\\expeditions.csv')
#create subset for success vs failure
exp_win_v_fail = exp[['termination_reason', 'basecamp_date', 'season']]
#drop successes in dispute
exp_win_v_fail = exp_win_v_fail[(exp_win_v_fail['termination_reason'] != 'Success (claimed)') & (exp_win_v_fail['termination_reason'] != 'Attempt rumoured')]
```

This is the part I can't figure out

```
#recode termination reason to be binary
for element in exp_win_v_fail['termination_reason']:
   if element == 'Success (main peak)':
     element = 1
   elif element == 'Success (subpeak)':
     element = 1
   else:
     element = 0
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: Do you realise that nothing in exp_win_v_fail will change with this code?

Comment: In your code you haven't written any lines to convert something to a datatype.

Comment: I think trying if 'Success (main peak)' in element: will work as sometimes there is a \n at the end specifying a line break. This may not happen in a dataset but in a .txt file it happens a lot. Maybe providing your data may help. Is it a csv file, excel file etc.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.
@ROOP AMBER I used this dataset https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/majunbajun/himalayan-climbing-expeditions

Comment: @LancelotduLac Could you please explain why?

Comment: @McJizzle91 If you edit the question to show what exp_win_v_fail is I'm sure someone will help you. Anything else is just guesswork at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace all values beginning with 'Success' with 1, and all other values to 0:

```
from pandas import read_csv

RE = '^Success.*$'
NRE = '^((?!Success).)*$'
TR = 'termination_reason'
BD = 'basecamp_date'
SE = 'season'

data = read_csv('expeditions.csv')

exp_win_v_fail = data[[TR, BD, SE]]

for v, re_ in enumerate((NRE, RE)):
    exp_win_v_fail[TR] = exp_win_v_fail[TR].replace(to_replace=re_, value=v, regex=True)

for e in exp_win_v_fail[TR]:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Any ideas why this won't work?


`# Turn the season column into a categorical
exp_win_v_fail['season'] = exp_win_v_fail['season'].astype('category')
exp_win_v_fail['season'].dtypes


from scipy.stats import f_oneway

# One-way ANOVA
f_value, p_value = f_oneway(exp_win_v_fail[SE], exp_win_v_fail[TR])
print("F-score: " + str(f_value))
print("p value: " + str(p_value))`